# How can I pass a parameter to the underlying table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table based on a view in SQLAlchemy:

```
class Aggregation(Base):
    __table__ = (
        select(
            func.sum(OtherTable.amount).label("amount"),
            SpotSettlement.currency,
        )
        .group_by(OtherTable.currency)
        .alias()
    )
```

I'd like to be able to pass in a parameter to the `__table__` an argument like a date, so for example:

```
class Aggregation(Base):
    __table__ = (
        select(
            func.sum(OtherTable.amount).label("amount"),
            SpotSettlement.currency,
        )
        # Pass this in somehow
        .where(OtherTable.created < $PARAMETER)
        .group_by(OtherTable.currency)
        .alias()
    )
```

Is there any SQLAlchemy magic that could allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One can use `bindparam` and pass it in with `Query.params`

```
from sqlalchemy impport bindparam

class Aggregation(Base):
    __table__ = (
        select(
            func.sum(OtherTable.amount).label("amount"),
            SpotSettlement.currency,
        )
        # Pass this in somehow
        .where(OtherTable.created < bindparam('created_before'))
        .group_by(OtherTable.currency)
        .alias()
    )


session.query(Aggregation).params(created_before=now)
```